# Callback when the activity is fully displayed

Tags: java, android

I want to fade in application's logo when the main page is loaded. I put the code in onResume function, the problem is that the fading starts before the page is displayed and I see it in the middle or sometimes even when it already ended.

How can I run it when the page is fully displayed to the user?

Comment: There are many (bad) ways to do this. You should show code.

Comment: This should have a generic answer regardless of the code

Answer (score 1):

You can override [Activity.onWindowFocusChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29)

when `hasFocus` is true, start your fading and set a member variable to avoid showing it again on next focus change.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unconventional answer, but [Android Annotations](http://androidannotations.org/) makes this easy. You can simply use the `@AfterViews` annotation before a function to make the code within it execute after the views are ready.